# Sauce lab automatically log bug into jira

Tags: automation, automated-tests, jira, saucelabs

We're looking into automation so we're facing the issue is sauce lab automatically logs bugs in Jira of fail test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Not only does Sauce Labs log failed test cases, we provide analytics and a dashboard to help you understand and find patterns in those failures.  You can [see an example here](https://training.saucelabs.com/codelabs/Module3-Quickstart/index.html?index=..%2F..quickstart#5) of how to add a 'test status' that is passed to the Sauce Labs Dashboard

```
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

//...
private String testName;
private String sessionId;
private SauceREST sauceClient;
// ...
 @Override
        protected void before() throws Exception {
            if (host.equals("saucelabs")) {
                MutableCapabilities sauceOptions = new MutableCapabilities();
                sauceOptions.setCapability("username", sauceUser);
                sauceOptions.setCapability("accessKey", sauceKey);
                sauceOptions.setCapability("name", testName);
                sauceOptions.setCapability("tunnelIdentifier", "walkerlj_tunnel_id" );
//                sauceOptions.setCapability("parentTunnel", "walkerlj");
                MutableCapabilities capabilities = new MutableCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browserName);
                capabilities.setCapability("browserVersion", browserVersion);
                capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
                capabilities.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);
                String sauceUrl = String.format("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub");
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(sauceUrl), capabilities);
                sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();
                sauceClient = new SauceREST(sauceUser, sauceKey, DataCenter.US);

// ...
  public TestRule watcher;{
    // ...
          @Override
          protected void failed(Throwable throwable, Description description) {
              if (host.equals("saucelabs")) {
                  sauceClient.jobFailed(sessionId);
                  System.out.println(String.format("https://saucelabs.com/tests/%s", sessionId));
              }
          }

          @Override
          protected void succeeded(Description description) {
              if (host.equals("saucelabs")) {
                  sauceClient.jobPassed(sessionId);
              }
          }
        };
// ...
```